# Python: Appending numerous 2D list to one 2D list

Tags: python, list, loops, 2d

For the sake of simplicity I will just use two lists.
So I have the following 2D lists:

```
> > a = [[1,2,3],
> >      [1,2,3]]   
> > b = [[4,5,6],
> >      [4,5,6]]
```

And if I append list a and b, I'm looking to obtain the following:

```
masterlist = [[1,4], [2,5], [3,6], [1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]
```

The following code is what I have tried:

```
filenames = [a,b]           #For the example, since I will have multiple arrays 
masterlist = [] 
counter = 0 
for file in filenames:
    if counter == 0:        #This if is to try to create lists within the list
        for row in file:    #This loops is to iterate throughout the whole list
                for col in row:
                    c = [masterlist.append([col])]
        [masterlist.append(c) for row, col in zip(masterlist, c)]
        counter = 1
    else:                   #This else is to append each element to their respective position
        for row in file:
                for col in row:
                    c = [masterlist.append(col)]
        [masterlist.append([c]) for row, col in zip(masterlist, c)]
```

The output when printing masterlist is the following:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [1], [2], [3], [None], 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, [[None]]]
```

I'm not sure where the [None]'s come from either. And as we can see '4,5,6...' aren't appended to the lists '[1], [2], [3]...' respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the items of the lists and then add them to your masterlist:

```
a = [[1,2,3],
     [1,2,3]]   
b = [[4,5,6],
     [4,5,6]]

masterlist = []

for aa,bb in zip(a,b):                 # loop over lists
    for itema, itemb in zip(aa,bb):    # loop over items in list
        masterlist = masterlist + [[itema, itemb]]
```

output:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use  numpy,this is really easy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
     [1,2,3]])
    
b = np.array([[4,5,6],
     [4,5,6]])

fl = np.vstack(np.dstack((a,b)))
```

output

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```